# FOUserundle-Synfony2.8 : 2 differents entities

Tags: symfony

I downloaded FOUSERBUNDLE but I have a problem when I add an instance entity.

I have a entity 'Person', it inherits User of FOUSERBUNDLE :

```
 class Person extends BaseUser{
     /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $firstname;
     ...
}
```

And I have two others entities and these entities inherits Person ! :

```
class Person1 extends Person{
    ...
    /* Same attributes that Person but differents associations */
    ...
}


 class Person2 extends Person{
    ...
    /* Same attributes that Person but differents associations */
    ...
 }
```

But the authentication with FOUSERBUNDLE use online one entity (Person).

**How can I add instance of Person1 or Person2 and login with this instance ?**

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle

> The PUGXMultiUserBundle extends FOSUserBundle adding the feature to
>   handle users of different types. For now only supports the ORM db
>   driver and is based on the doctrine2 inheritance.

Comment: I want, if it's possible, avoid this bundle because there are not many documentations